# Firebase Gmail Login googleCredential.getId() is it always email?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have implemented a Gmail One Tap login using Firebase using the following [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

After account selection:

```
SignInCredential credential = signInClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data);
credential.getId()  // this id
```

The credential id is my Gmail account. What I would like to confirm is whether that is always email.

Comment: So to be more clear, the `credential` object is `null`, right? Where in code are you using these lines of code?

Comment: It is not null. But the id is email. I want to confirm that ID is always email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment:

> But the id is email. I want to confirm that ID is always email?

According to official documentation of the [SignInCredential#getId()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInCredential#getId()) method:

> Returns the identifier of the credential. For an ID token credential, this returns the **email address** of the user's account and for a password-backed credential, it returns the **username** for that password.

So not, it is **not** always the email. It might also be a username.